# Want value as number, number is that bar number of highest intraday price of stock from opening

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

[Image to clear what output is needed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbbpD.jpg)had tried multiple logic to get exact bar number from opening of market where stock price was highest/lowest, Please suggest a better whole code.

e.g. attached image, where i want value 11 as output for day low bar via pine/tradingview script. it's today 23Jan23 chart for Nifty50 Index.

Comment: You forgot to attach your screenshots and code.

Comment: and somehow instead of that, you put the same text twice...

Comment: @vitruvius added Image.

Comment: In the example: why Bar number is 11? How did you get to that value?

Comment: And add your code too please.

Comment: not know much coding, Bar no 11 is low time bar no - open time bar no. @Gu5tavo71

Comment: What is bar number 1?

Comment: @Gu5tavo71 Opening bar of session

Answer (score 0):

About this:

> suggest a better whole code

This is not a code writing service. I will give you a guide:

1. To identify the first bar of the session use [session.isfirstbar](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#var_session%7Bdot%7Disfirstbar)
2. Count the bars using [ta.barssince](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_ta%7Bdot%7Dbarssince)
3. find the maximum value with [math.max](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_math%7Bdot%7Dmax) and minimum with [math.min](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_math%7Bdot%7Dmin)